# set post request body to form-data objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, form-data

I am trying to send `form-data` in a **post request body** but the service is returning null so either the method i am using is wrong (it was generated by postman) or the image encoding is different, i will show you how the image is supposed to be encoded and how i am encoding it through the screenshots below besides the code i use

```
NSString* imgName = [self randomCode];
    NSString* postFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",imgName,userData.userID];
    
    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAt4JdBdihQo7lrrf",
                               @"authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",userData.accessToken ],
                               @"moduleid": @"441",
                               @"tabid": @"78",
                               @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"1482fe03-076b-aa92-5565-125212592762" };
    NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"folder", @"value": userData.userFolder },
                             @{ @"name": @"filter", @"value": @"bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,jpe,png" },
                             @{ @"name": @"overwrite", @"value": @"true" },
                             @{ @"name": @"postfile", @"fileName": postFile } ];
    NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundaryAt4JdBdihQo7lrrf";
    
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
        [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
        if (param[@"fileName"]) {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", @"image/png"];
            
            NSString* imgString = [self encodeToBase64String:self.teamImage];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@", imgString];

            ;
        } else {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@\n", param[@"value"]];
        }
    }
    [body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
    NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.0.216/API/internalservices/fileupload/postfile"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];


- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData * data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
}
```

here is how the image should look like when the server receives is :
[image]
and here is how the server receive it from me :
[image]

please tell me what i am doing wrong

thanks

Comment: You say you want a base64 string, but you're using a mime type of image/png (which should not be a base 64 string). And the way you're sending the data is neither the binary data nor the base 64 string. Usually when we use `multipart/form-data` requests, we're doing it so we can send the binary data, as pckill suggested. In terms of why the result is `null`, we'd need to know what response the server was supposed to send. Perhaps show us the server code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the server does not expect the image to be base64-encoded. In order to submit a non-encoded image you can construct post data directly without an intermediate `NSMutableString` object:

```
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data];
for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
    [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if (param[@"fileName"]) {
        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", @"image/png"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [postData appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.teamImage)];
    } else {
        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", param[@"value"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
}
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: still the result is null :((

Comment: status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 143;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 14:42:59 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    "Proxy-Connection" = "Keep-alive";
    "Set-Cookie" = "dnn_IsMobile=False; path=/; HttpOnly, language=en-US; path=/; HttpOnly";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
}

Comment: Do you control the server? Can you debug the problem there or maybe send a more informative error description?